# Intersection of an exponential function and a line

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

I am trying to solve an equation of the form $e^{x}=m \cdot x+b$. Ideally, I would like to have a solution as a closed form, although the exact method is escaping me as to how this can be done. How can I solve this kind of equation using a closed form, if at all?

Comment: your solution(s) will contain the Lambert W function, is that ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As qbert already commented, welcome to the wonderful world of [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) !

As the Wikipedia page will show you, a series of transformations would lead to
$$x=-W\left(-\frac{1}{m}e^{-\frac{b}{m}}\right)-\frac{b}{m}$$ where $W(z)$ is the solution of $z=W(z)\, e^{W(z)}$.

Now, the problem is : how many solutions ?

Basically, you are looking for the zero(s) of function
$$f(x)=e^x-mx-b$$ $$f'(x)=e^x-m$$ $$f''(x)=e^x >0\qquad \forall x$$ The first derivative could cancel for $x_*=\log(m)$; this could only happen if $m>0$.
$$f(x_*)=-b+m(1- \log (m))$$ So, if $f(x_*) <0$, you would get two roots corresponding to different branches of Lambert function.

Comment: Never heard of the Lambert function, will have to do some studying about this. Wonder if I can find a C# library that has it already... Good to know I might get two answers from this, I think I'll only want the higher one, but...

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto. Go to the Wiki page and search on this site. There are more and more uses of it. In fact, any equation which can write or rewrite $a+b x+c \log(dx+e)=0$ has solutions in terms of Lambert function.

Comment: Managed to get it figured out, thanks for all of the help!

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto. You are very welcome.