# How do you solve this formula $(1 + 0.02X) ^{1/X} = 1.0161$

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

$X$ is supposed to be the duration of the loan in years.

The number $0.02$ stands for the nominal interest and the $1.0161$ stands for the compound interest + $1$.

The equation can also be written : $(1 + X/50)^{1/X} = 1.0161$

To use the right logarithm for this is difficult but is it possible to solve?

For example with $\log [(1+0,02x)^{1/x}] = \log (1,0161)$.
Or with  $1/x \cdot \log (1+ 0,02x) = \log (1,0161)$
Or with $\ln$?

Comment: Please use MathJax to write mathematics. Else it is too hard to read and interpret.  I've edited to show this (once accepted). Also I think you mean compound not composed interest.

Comment: what is $X$ measured in? Years?

Comment: yes in years is X

Comment: I don't think there's a closed-form solution, but the numerical solution is $X \approx 27.18154399276448$.

Comment: There is a product log solution [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1%2Bx%2F50%3D1.0161%5Ex%2C10%3Cx%3C30)

Comment: Usually in these nominal/compound interest problems you take $ln$ or a root of both sides, but with the variable being time I agree it won't be solvable algebraically.  But you can get the above answer very quickly e.g. Solver in Excel.

Comment: In addition to an answer given by @Dan you may check [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2632170/intersection-of-an-exponential-function-and-a-line).

Comment: lIs it possible with og (1+0,02x)^1/x = log (1,0161)
Or with  1/x log (1+ 0,02x) = log (1,0161)?